# Why is the getElementsByTagNameNS empty in java?

Tags: java, xml

I want to get the value out tag2 and I got this a xml:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<ns1:schema xmlns:ns1='http://example.com'>" +
                "<ns1:tag1>" +
                "    <ns1:tag2>value</ns1:tag2>" +
                "</ns1:tag1>" +
            "</ns1:schema>";
```

Then parse it to a document and want to get the elements by tagnameNS. But when I run this the nodelist is empty why?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))); 

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.com", "tag2");

        String a = nl.item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Still doesnt work with the URI.

Comment: Unrelated, but in my quest to reduce encoding-related problems worldwide, I'd advise you to replace `new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())` with `new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getElementsByTagNameNS` is returing a result.  The issue is that you're currently calling the wrong method to get the text content off the result elements.  You need to call `getTextContext()` and not `getNodeValue()`

```
String a = nl.item(0).getTextContent();
```

**DomDemo**

Below is a complete code example.

```
package forum13166195;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class DomDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                   + "<ns1:schema xmlns:ns1='http://example.com'>"
                       + "<ns1:tag1>"
                           + "<ns1:tag2>value</ns1:tag2>"
                       + "</ns1:tag1>"
                   + "</ns1:schema>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))); 

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.com", "tag2");

        String a = nl.item(0).getTextContent();
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
value
```

---

**ALTERNATE APPROACH**

You can also use the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs (included in Java SE 5 and above) to query a value from an XML document. These APIs offer a lot more control than `getElementsByTagNameNS`.

**XPathDemo**

```
package forum13166195;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                   + "<ns1:schema xmlns:ns1='http://example.com'>"
                       + "<ns1:tag1>"
                           + "<ns1:tag2>value</ns1:tag2>"
                       + "</ns1:tag1>"
                   + "</ns1:schema>";

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

            public String getNamespaceURI(String arg0) {
                if("a".equals(arg0)) {
                    return "http://example.com";
                }
                return null;
            }

            public String getPrefix(String arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            public Iterator getPrefixes(String arg0) {
                return null;
            }

        });

        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        String result = (String) xpath.evaluate("/a:schema/a:tag1/a:tag2", inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
value
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 Try this :

  DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));      
  NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "tag2");
  String a = nodeList.item(0).getTextContent();
  System.out.println(a);
```

**Output**

```
value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the namespace URL; not the local alias you created in the XML.