# Getting a grandson element from XML directly

Tags: java, xml

I have been looking for XML read examples in JAVA, and I always find a typical schema root->3 equal sons->3 equal grandsons.

But sometimes you just have to get a pair of elements which are not stored like a library with books{title, author, number of pages}. My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<A>
    <Crap1>
        <CrapSon>1</CrapSon>
    </Crap1>
    <B>
        <Crap2>Store</Crap2>
        <C>
            <Type>N</Type>
            <D>
                <InterestingData1>Data</InterestingData1>
            </D>
            <InterestingData2>More Data</InterestingData2>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Of course, I could iterate it all and finally get to the data elements I want. But is there any fast way of accessing those elements you want without iterating the tree, just by name and letting it search for it?

Comment: [XPATH](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/12/xpath.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `javax.xml.xpath` library in Java SE 5 and above and use XPath to query the document for the data you want.

**Example**

- [Why is the getElementsByTagNameNS empty in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166195/why-is-the-getelementsbytagnamens-empty-in-java/13167056#13167056)

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

class Test {    

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        String xmlString ="<A>" +
                "<Crap1><CrapSon>1</CrapSon>" +
                "</Crap1>" +
                "<B>" +
                "<Crap2>Store</Crap2><C><Type>N</Type><D><InterestingData1>Data</InterestingData1></D><InterestingData2>More Data</InterestingData2></C>" +
                "</B>" +
                "</A>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();      
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));

        NodeList nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("InterestingData2");
        NodeList nodelist2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Type");

        String str = nodelist.item(0).getTextContent();
        String str2 = nodelist2.item(0).getTextContent();

        System.out.println("InterestingData2: "+str);
        System.out.println("Type: " + str2);
    }
}
```

output:

InterestingData2: More Data

Type: N

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the DOM, I guess you should use a SAX parser with a handler for processing `InterestingData1` and `InterestingData2`.